# Dota 2 api "Player Slot" text representation

Tags: steam-web-api

From https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/WebAPI/GetMatchDetails we know "A player's slot is returned via an 8-bit unsigned integer. The first bit represent the player's team, false if Radiant and true if dire. The final three bits represent the player's position in that team, from 0-4." Ok from final three bits we have a number position 0-4 BUT i need text representation this values.

Can someone write a current list of player position matching? I think it should look something like this, but I'm not sure.
Example:
0 - full support
1 - support
2 - hard
3 - mid
4 - safe
Regards

Comment: Are you asking a question? do you need help with something?

Comment: I edit my question. Regards